# Firebase SignUp always gives an error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am implementing Fire-Base Authentication in my app, With SignUp and SignIn, however i am having a problem, every time i fill the form and click on the SignUp button the Fire-Base gives back an error even though the account was successfully created. My code for the SignUp method:

```
    public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText input_email,input_pass;

private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    //View
    input_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_email);
    input_pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_pass);

    //Init Firebase
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void iLogin (View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this, Login.class));
        finish();
    }

public void iForgot(View v){
        //startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this, ForgotPassword.class));
        finish();
    }

public void iSignUp(View v){
        signUpUser(input_email.getText().toString(),input_pass.getText().toString());
    }

private void signUpUser(String email, String password) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Successfully created your account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ERROR has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
      }
}
```

So what happens is:

1- The user Opens the app for the first time, the app opens mainly on the MainActivity.class which then redirects the user to the SignUp.class (The one i have added above).

2- The user then fills two fields: (Email) and (Password) and clicks on the SignUp button

3- The SignUp.class (The one i have added above) then creates a new account and shows the Toast: ERROR has occurred, even though the account has been created successfully. In order for the class to display the correct Toast (Successfully created your account) i need to press on the button a second time.

So just to be clear: The first time you click, the account is created and i can see it in Fire-Base Console but the app still gives the wrong Toast, for it to show the correct one i need to click it again, Any thoughts on what's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
if(!task.isSuccessful())
```

to:

```
if(task.isSuccessful())
```

and it should work. There is a success when `task.isSuccessful()` is true, so the `!` sign make it false. That's why it works for the second time.